# Java Matrix how to assign int 1 or 0 to a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Here is part of my code. I want to assign random number to the matrix population[][] first, then compare the random number to a specific number ranP, if population[][] < ranP, then re-assign population[][] to 1, otherwise 0. But it shows

```
arrayindexoutofboundsexception 0
```

Need help on the issue. Thanks!

```
            randGen = new Random();
            double randNum = randGen.nextDouble();

            for ( int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
                for (int k = 0; k < inipopulationsize; k++){
                    for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++){



                        ranP = 0.5;
                        //TMaxtrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
                        System.out.println(matrix[i][j] + " ");
                        population = new double[k][j];
                        System.out.println("randNum: " + randNum);
                        population[k][j] = randNum;
                        if (randNum <= ranP){
                            population[k][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else
                            population[k][j] = 0;
                        System.out.println("population: " + population[k][j]);

                    }//j loop


                }//k loop

            }//i loop
```

I am learning this by myself, and not taking any classes. If this really bothers you "experts", why dont you just ignore and save your time go home watching a movie or spending more time with your family? Appreciate the help from nice people here. But shame on you who only knows sarcasm. Here is what works finally:

```
            randGen = new Random();
            population = new int[inipopulationsize][25];

            for ( int i = 0; i < population.length; i++){

                    for (int j = 0; j < population[i].length; j++){
                        double randNum = randGen.nextDouble();
                        ranP = 0.5;
                        if (i < 11){
                        //System.out.println(matrix[i][j] + " ");
                        }

                        if (randNum <= ranP){
                            population[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else
                            population[i][j] = 0;
                    //System.out.println("population index: " + i + " Dieasease index: " + j + " DI on (1) or off (0): " + population[i][j] + "");

                    }//j loop


            }//i loop
```

Comment: You **have to read [ask]**

Comment: Please update your code to show how you instantiated the variables population and matrix

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do here. Please edit your question to explain clearly what your end goal is. Is it a 2D array with randomly distributed 1's and 0's or a matrix of such arrays? It is a bit hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the third loop because you want i 2d arrays? If so you should probably look at ArrayLists of 2d arrays.

```
        int inipopulationsize = 25;
        double[][] population;
        Random randGen = new Random();
        double randNum = randGen.nextDouble();
        double ranP = 0.5;// outside loops
        population = new double[inipopulationsize][25]; // out


            for (int k = 0; k < inipopulationsize; k++){
                for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++){

                    randNum = randGen.nextDouble();//i assume you want new random every time

                    if (randNum <= ranP){
                        population[k][j] = 1;
                    }
                    else
                        population[k][j] = 0;
                }//j loop
            }//k loop
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(population));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason for having 3 loops with a 2d array.

```
Random randGen = new Random(); 
double randNum;
for(int i=0; i<population.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<population[i].length; j++){
        randNum = ranGen.nextDouble();
        if(randNum<0.5) population[i][j] = 0;
        else population[i][j] = 1.0;
    }//j loop
}//i loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are referring to an item *outside* the bounds of your 2D array.

Let's take a look at your code. This line: `population = new double[k][j];` declares a new 2D arrays of size `k`x`j`. Then in this line: `population[k][j] = randNum;` you try to reference the item in the kth column and jth row of this same 2D array. **This is not legal in Java arrays.**

Java arrays are 0-indexed, which means with an array of size `k`, your indexes range from `0` to `k-1`. There is no item at index `k`. This is why you are receiving an index out of bounds error.

[Please look at this link instructing you on the basic use of Java Arrays.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

The exact error `arrayindexoutofboundsexception 0` appears because on your first iteration, you create a population of size 0 by 0. Then you try to access the item in column 0 and row 0, that is to say, the first item. However as your population array has 0 size, it has no space, and even the index 0 is out of bounds.

---

However, I am not even sure this is what you want to be doing.

You are declaring a 2D array on *each iteration* of your loop. If all you are trying to do is make a single array of size `inipopulationsize`by`25` (these are the initial values of `k` and `j`) then you need to declare this *outside* of these two nested loops. Perhaps even outside of the third loop, as I am not even sure what that loop is doing.

Take a loop at [anaxin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35070612/3745896) for how to effectively assign 0's and 1's to your population array randomly. (With `randP` set to `0.5` you are giving each a 50% chance of appearing.)